# Nvidia CUDA N-Body Simulation sample doesn't compile on Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, cuda, nvidia

I downloaded and installed:

Visual Studio 2010
CUDA Toolkit 4.1
N-Body Simulation sample(extracted to desktop in a folder called "NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK")

When I opened the nbody_vs2010.sln inside "NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK\C\src\nbody" , I got 2 could not be found errors for:

NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK\shared\shrUtils_vs2010.vcxproj
NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK\C\common\cutil_vs2010.vcxproj

When am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I read this to mean that you downloaded the individual n-body sample [here](http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-cc-sdk-code-samples#nbody) rather than the complete SDK.  I just downloaded that package and confirmed that it is missing the shrUtils library (it has the headers, but no source or project files).  This is a bug.

For now, to work around the issue, please download the entire SDK package ([32-bit](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/sdk/gpucomputingsdk_4.1.28_win_32.exe) or [64-bit](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/sdk/gpucomputingsdk_4.1.28_win_64.exe)), and I will report the problem!

Comment: I downloaded the entire SDK and tried to compile the N-Body Simulation program in Visual Studio 2010. The program compiled, but I got an error that says "Unable to start program 'C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK 4.1\C\common\lib\cutil.dll' The system cannot find the file specified. "

Comment: Make sure you build the projects in the ...\C\common folder (the cutil library).  Please read the readme/release notes included with the SDK for full instructions.

Comment: Wrapping my head around a similair problem with `particles`. So, GPU computing SDK and CUDA SDK are different things then? (I've got CUDA sdk, and searching for the direct link to GPU sdk (like) yours yesterday returned nothing (so I -- erroneously -- assumed they are the same)). Seems like both http://developer.nvidia.com/gpu-computing-sdk and http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads have no links like yours. Isn't it a bug by itself? (I assume you're somehow affiliated with NVIDIA). And thanks for the help, of course!

Comment: We are in the process of improving the CUDA downloads, naming, and website, so thanks for your patience.  Those SDKs are the same.  Currently, that big green button on the CUDA downloads page takes you to the current CUDA version (4.1) downloads page, which has the per-OS SDK downloads on it.  Here: http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-41